# Resolution of an append to an empty array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I noticed something odd demonstrated below:

```
>>> print [].append(1)
None

>>> a = [].append(1)
>>> print a
None

>>> a = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> print a
[1]
```

I do not understand what the difference between the first two statements and the last one is. Can anyone explain?

EDIT:

This question was asked poorly. I should also have noted that:

```
>>> print [] + [1]
[1]
```

Thank you for explaining that the return value for operations on mutable data-types in python is normally None.

Comment: How does last example remotely resemble the first two?

Comment: `List.append`  dosen't return anything so first two statements will be `None` but third one is a list with appended element

Comment: `list.append` mutates its list and returns `None`. This is a standard convention in Python for functions and methods that perform mutation on an object, like the `list.` methods. In contrast, Python strings are immutable, so `str.` methods cannot mutate their target object, they must return a new object.

Comment: Thank you PM 2Ring, mutable vs immutable was my real question, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.append()` method does not return a modified list as you would expect.
With this line `a = [].append(1)` you're assigning the return value (which is `None` in Python by default) to the variable `a`. You're not assigning an array that you've just appended to.
However, with this code

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(1)
```

you're modifying the array in the variable `a`.